# Exception in thread "main" java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Why am I getting errors??? I use eclipse, the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>             at Shopping_Booket.Movie_assign(Shopping_Booket.java:8)
>                 at AcmeVideo.main(AcmeVideo.java:8)

The code:

```
public class AcmeVideo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shopping_Booket shop = new Shopping_Booket();
        shop.Movie_assign();
    }
}

public class Shopping_Booket {

    movie[] MovieArray = new movie[5];

    public void Movie_assign() {

        MovieArray[0].Assign("Batman Dark Knight Return", 8, 2012, 22);
        MovieArray[1].Assign("Fringe", 9.2, 2008, 40);
        MovieArray[2].Assign("V for Vandetta", 8, 2005, 28);
        MovieArray[3].Assign("X man First Class", 7, 2005, 30);
        MovieArray[4].Assign("Hulk", 8.5, 2000, 16);
        System.out.println(MovieArray[2].Title);
    }
}

public class movie {

    public String Title;
    public double Rating;
    public int Year;
    public double Price;

    public void Assign(String title, double rating, int year, double price) {
        this.Title = title;
        this.Rating = rating;
        this.Year = year;
        this.Price = price;
    }

    public void Displayİnfo() {
        System.out.println("Title = " + Title);
        System.out.println("Year = " + Year);
        System.out.println("Rating = " + Rating);
        System.out.println("Price = " + Price);
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Please don't use class names like `Shopping_Booket`, `movie`. Method names like `Movie_assign()`. They don't confirm the Java naming convention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have created an array, but you have never created instances. Your array is simply an array of null objects.

```
movie [] MovieArray=new movie [5];
```

Currently `movie` looks like this:

```
{null, null, null, null, null}
```

And what you need to do is add some instances to it.

```
MovieArray[0] = new Movie(// etc);
```

**Just to note**

The Java naming conventions state that variables that are not constants must begin with a lower case letter, and all subsequent words start with an upper case letter.

```
MovieArray -> movieArray
```

Answer (score 3):

This declaration:

```
movie [] MovieArray=new movie [5];
```

... creates a new array with 5 elements, but each element is null to start with. You never actually create a new instance of the `movie()` class. Instead, you're calling your `Assign` method on a null reference each time - and that's what's causing the exception.

See the [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) part of the Java tutorial for a bit more information on arrays.

You should change your `Assign` method into a constructor, and then write:

```
MovieArray[0] = new movie("Batman Dark Knight Return", 8, 2012, 22);
```

You should then *definitely* read up on [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html):

- Your class should be `Movie`, not `movie`
- Your variables should start with a lower case letter (`title`, not `Title`)
- Ditto your methods: `displayInfo` etc

I'd also *strongly* advise you to use private fields instead of public ones.

Comment: Not sure why mine was voted up more than yours. +1 for a thorough answer!